# MUD programming - map with graphical background

Tags: java, game-engine, mud

I'm currently working on a MUD project.  I'd like to figure out how to use a static background IMAGE as a map. (These maps are like graph paper.  Squares represent rooms, and lines connect the squares to show cardinal direction exits.)  There will be custom "hand-drawn" maps for each area in the game.

On my GUI, there will be a section of the frame dedicated to showing this static map.  When a player MOVES (goes east, west, northwest, etc), a red DOT will be drawn over the current room the player is in.

This is similar to other MUD maps, except in most cases those maps are ASCII/text.  I would really like to be able to use an image as the background, and only "draw" the red dot representing player location.

Also, the distance between rooms would not be uniform, so I cannot blindly just move the dot say 50 pixels left for a western movement.

How would I go about programming this?  I imagine I will need to pre-define where the dot would be displayed for each room.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, if moving the dot is not possible, I'd also be open to having the red dot STAY centered, with the BACKGROUND IMAGE being shifted within the JLabel's viewing area.

Comment: Even just a library/javadoc reference?  I'm desperate here.